# Osgviewer cow does not view a cow?

Tags: macports, openscenegraph

I installed `OpenSceneGraph 3.0.1`using `MacPorts`.

I've tried `osgversion` -> `OpenSceneGraph Library 3.0.1`. I downloaded the `OpenSceneGraph-Data`.

Everything seems working well than `osgviewer cow.osg` takes hours without viewing anything !

please I need help ? is there a way to debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the `OSG_FILE_PATH` environment variable and that it points to the data directory (the one with 'cow.osg').

You can then set `OSG_NOTIFY_LEVEL` to `DEBUG_INFO` to get extended information printed to the console. If for any reason the file could not be loaded correctly you will see where to start to troubleshoot.

You can also try to run

```
$ osgviewer --image /path/to/an/image.png
```

to test if the plugins work correctly.

Plugins are named e.g. `osgdb_jpeg.dylib` so you can look for these to make sure they have been built properly along with the core libraries and programs.

Comment: `Warning: Could not find plugin to read objects from file "Cubemap_snow/negx.jpg".`

How to set those variables on `Mac OS X Mountain Lion`` please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the notify level to DEBUG : [Tips And Tricks](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Support/TipsAndTricks)

```
$ export OSG_NOTIFY_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

and run it and see if it says what's going on/going wrong.